# Reading other parameters in KeyEvent method Java FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm currently making a 2d Grid game where the character moves on WASD (and also on screen buttons, but that's a feature for later). My keyevent method doesn't allow for other parameters to be read into it, so the code doesn't run. Not sure how to code it to allow other parameters. Here is the code for the listener

Ideally, I would like to be able to run something like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e, Player player, Cell[][] goldPosition etc.) {

        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.W) {
            player.moveUp(player);
            detectMovement(goldPosition, trapPosition, player, pane_Board, applePosition);
```

EDIT: I was told to add executable code, so I included most things to be sure. But really, I just need to know how to execute keyevent code that will allow extra parameters inside it. Thanks

```
package minergame.gui;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import minergame.engine.*;


import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Controller {
    private GameEngine engine = new GameEngine(10);
    private int score = 0;
    private int d = 5;

    @FXML
    private Label lbl_Score;

    @FXML
    private Label lbl_Stamina;

    @FXML
    private GridPane pane_Board;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane border_Pane;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        //instantiate player class
        Player player = new Player();

        //Scoreboard for score and stamina

        lbl_Score.setText("Score: " + Integer.toString(score));

      lbl_Stamina.setText("Stamina: " + Integer.toString(player.getStamina()));



        /**
         * TO DO
         * HBox scoreboard is irrelevant now. Labels are used, need to be replaced throughout code when updating
         *score and stamina etc.
         */


        //gold coord list
        Cell[][] goldPosition = new Cell[10][10];

        //trap coord list
        Cell[][] trapPosition = new Cell[10][10];

        //apple coord list
        Cell[][] applePosition = new Cell[10][10];

        //prompt user to select difficulty
        //selectDifficulty();
        //initialise the game map
        createMap(pane_Board, player, goldPosition, trapPosition, applePosition);

        //FOR DEBUGGING print gold location
        for(int i = 0; i < goldPosition.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < goldPosition.length; j++) {
                if (goldPosition[i][j]!=null)
                System.out.println("row:"+ i + " col: " + j);
            }
        }

    } 

    @FXML
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        //KEYCODE W
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.W) {
            player.moveUp(player);
            detectMovement(goldPosition, trapPosition, player, pane_Board, applePosition);
            updateGUI(pane_Board, goldPosition, player, trapPosition, applePosition);

        } //KEYCODE D
        else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.D) {
            player.moveRight(player);
            detectMovement(goldPosition, trapPosition, player, pane_Board, applePosition);
            updateGUI(pane_Board, goldPosition, player, trapPosition, applePosition);

        } //KEYCODE S
        else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.S) {
            player.moveDown(player);
            detectMovement(goldPosition, trapPosition, player, pane_Board, applePosition);
            updateGUI(pane_Board, goldPosition, player, trapPosition, applePosition);

        } //KEYCODE A
        else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
            player.moveLeft(player);
            detectMovement(goldPosition, trapPosition, player, pane_Board, applePosition);
            updateGUI(pane_Board, goldPosition, player, trapPosition, applePosition);
        }
    }

    //this needs to be changed or deleted
    public void updateScore(HBox scoreBoard, Player player) {
        scoreBoard.getChildren().clear();
        scoreBoard.getChildren().add(new Text("Score: " + Integer.toString(score)));
        scoreBoard.getChildren().add(new Text("Stamina: " + Integer.toString(player.getStamina())));
    }

    @FXML
    public void detectMovement(Cell[][] goldPosition, Cell[][] trapPosition, Player player,
                               GridPane pane, Cell[][] applePosition) {
        //detect gold
        if (goldPosition[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] instanceof Gold) {
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            goldPosition[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] = null;
            pane.add(engine.getMap()[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] = player, player.getPlayerCol(),
                    player.getPlayerRow());
            score++;
            player.setStamina(player.getStamina()+1);

            //detect trap
        } else if (trapPosition[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] instanceof Trap) {
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            pane.add(engine.getMap()[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] = player, player.getPlayerCol(),
                    player.getPlayerRow());
            player.setStamina(player.getStamina() - 4);


            //detect apple
        } else if (applePosition[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] instanceof Apple) {
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            applePosition[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] = null;
            pane.add(engine.getMap()[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] = player, player.getPlayerCol(),
                    player.getPlayerRow());
            player.setStamina(player.getStamina()+3);

        } else {
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            pane.add(engine.getMap()[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] = player, player.getPlayerCol(),
                    player.getPlayerRow());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void updateGUI(GridPane pane, Cell[][] goldPosition, Player player,
                          Cell[][] trapPosition, Cell[][] applePosition) {
        //repopulate grid
        for (int i = 0; i < engine.getSize(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < engine.getSize(); j++) {
                pane.add(engine.getMap()[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);
            }
        }
        addGold(goldPosition, pane_Board);
        addTrap(trapPosition, pane_Board);
        addApple(applePosition, pane_Board);
        //updateScore(scoreBoard, player);
    }

    public void selectDifficulty() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Let's play! Enter difficulty to start (0 - 10)");
        d = input.nextInt();
    }

    @FXML
    public void createMap(GridPane pane, Player player, Cell[][] goldPosition, Cell[][] trapPosition,
                          Cell[][] applePosition) {
        //create map
        for (int i = 0; i < engine.getSize(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < engine.getSize(); j++) {
                pane.add(engine.getMap()[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);
            }
        }

        //add player to random position on map
        Random random = new Random();
        player.setPlayerRow(random.nextInt(engine.getSize()));
        player.setPlayerCol(random.nextInt(engine.getSize()));
        pane.add(engine.getMap()[player.getPlayerRow()][player.getPlayerCol()] = player, player.getPlayerCol(),
                player.getPlayerRow());

        //add gold to random positions on map
        int goldCount = 0;
        while(goldCount < 10) {
            int randomRow2 = random.nextInt(engine.getSize());
            int randomCol2 = random.nextInt(engine.getSize());
            if (randomRow2 != player.getPlayerRow() && randomCol2 != player.getPlayerCol() &&
                    !(goldPosition[randomRow2][randomCol2] instanceof Gold)) {
                goldCount++;
                goldPosition[randomRow2][randomCol2] = new Gold();
            }
        }
        addGold(goldPosition, pane_Board);

        //add traps to random positions on map
        int trapCount = 0;
        while(trapCount < d) {
            int randomRow3 = random.nextInt(engine.getSize());
            int randomCol3 = random.nextInt(engine.getSize());
            if (randomRow3 != player.getPlayerRow() && randomCol3 != player.getPlayerCol() &&
                    !(goldPosition[randomRow3][randomCol3] instanceof Gold) &&
                    !(goldPosition[randomRow3][randomCol3] instanceof Trap)) {
                trapPosition[randomRow3][randomCol3] = new Trap();
                trapCount++;
            }
        }
        addTrap(trapPosition, pane_Board);

        //add apples to random positions on map
        int appleCount = 0;
        while(appleCount < (15 - d)) {
            int randomRow4 = random.nextInt(engine.getSize());
            int randomCol4 = random.nextInt(engine.getSize());
            if (randomRow4 != player.getPlayerRow() && randomCol4 != player.getPlayerCol() &&
                    !(goldPosition[randomRow4][randomCol4] instanceof Apple) &&
                    !(goldPosition[randomRow4][randomCol4] instanceof Gold) &&
                    !(trapPosition[randomRow4][randomCol4] instanceof Trap)) {
                applePosition[randomRow4][randomCol4] = new Apple();
                appleCount++;
            }
        }
        addApple(applePosition, pane_Board);
    }

    public void addGold(Cell[][] list, GridPane pane) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                if (list[i][j] != null)
                    pane.add(list[i][j] = new Gold(), j, i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addTrap(Cell[][] list, GridPane pane) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                if (list[i][j] != null)
                    pane.add(list[i][j] = new Trap(), j, i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addApple(Cell[][] list, GridPane pane) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                if (list[i][j] != null)
                    pane.add(list[i][j] = new Apple(), j, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The FXML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>


<BorderPane id="border_Pane" onKeyPressed="#keyPressed" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="minergame.gui.Controller">
   <top>
      <HBox id="scoreBoard" prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="lbl_Score" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Score">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="lbl_Stamina" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Stamina">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children></HBox>
   </top>
   <center>
      <GridPane fx:id="pane_Board" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="10" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="10" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="10" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="10" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="10" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
   </center>
   <right>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="placeholder" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

Cells (Gold, Apple etc)

```
package minergame.engine;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class Cell extends Pane {


    public Cell() {
        setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
        this.setPrefSize(100,100);
    }
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra I included more code, thank you

Comment: Consider declaring those as fields instead of local variables. Taking a look at the methods you want to pass those values basically everywhere; you can remove those parameters, if these values are available via fields...

Comment: good starter - now make it a) minimal and b) reproducible :) For a) you have problems passing parameters - all you need to provide is a to handle a single key, not all of them. Also, all the calls to other methods are unrelated, simply do a some printout in that single key handler b) it's not reproducible for any of us because of GameEngine (which isn't needed, see a) As an aside: please stick to java naming conventions. All that said: @fabian nailed it :)